# Can't use 'metadata-only' URI to send messages

Tags: rest, gmail-api

I'm trying to replicate the function of the API Explorer found at the bottom of the page at:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send
I've figured out how to create a base64 encoded message and can get the API Explorer to send a message, but I am trying to replicate the result in the "Advanced REST Client" Chrome app.

I've set my url to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send
```

I've added the following headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer (valid Oauth2 token here)

Content-Type: message/rfc822
```

And set the body to:

```
{"raw":"Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PSJ1cy1hc2NpaSINCk1JTUUtVmVyc2lvbjogMS4wDQpDb250ZW50LVRyYW5zZmVyLUVuY29kaW5nOiA3Yml0DQp0bzogYnJ5Y2VAdGhvcm1lZGlhLmNvbQ0KZnJvbTogYnJ5Y2VAdGhvcm1lZGlhLmNvbQ0Kc3ViamVjdDogVGVzdA0KDQpIZWxsbyE="}
```

When I send the request, I get back the response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "wrongUrlForUpload",
    "message": "Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send"
 }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to form my request to allow me to use the metadata URI. The documentation for the API seems to focus almost exclusively on the upload URI, so understanding this is a bit rough.

Comment: Are you using the same sample code mentioned in this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: I used the python example on that page to make sure that I generated a valid base64 encoded message, but beyond that the code doesn't do anything to help me understand the REST API since it is all abstracted away in the client library. I've been digging through the source of the python library to try and get an idea, but I don't understand 90% of what is going on in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the Advanced REST Client, but a valid ajax request would be:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send",
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({"raw": mail}) // The url-safe base64 encoded mail
```

In other words, I think you are using the wrong contentType; it should be "application/json", not "message/rfc822", when you are sending an object with a "raw"-parameter.

Comment: That did it. I suppose it is implied that it should be JSON as it is a JSON object I am passing. I guess the issue is that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) goes out of it's way to state that the 'message/rfc822' Content-Type header should be used, with no mention of any alternative. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I agree. The documentation still has its flaws :) Glad I could help!

Comment: @Tholle could you explain the difference between how you passed the accessToken above vs how you did it in [this answer](http://iswwwup.com/t/ac988340c77b/node.js-send-email-using-google-api-with-only-access-token.html)? Your answer above worked for me but I could not get the linked answer to work and I don't understand why.

Comment: @DanKlos They should be equivalent. What error are you getting? Having a header `Authorization` with the string `'Bearer <your_access_token>'` as value should do it!

Comment: @Tholle It was of the 400-variety but I don't recall exactly now. Knowing that they are equivalent I'm sure it was just a syntax error on my part--I'm pretty new.